# ADF XML not being parsed by email receiver

Tags: php, xml, email

I built a program with GravityForms (Wordpress-based, but not relevant specifically to Wordpress) that takes data from lead entry forms and outputs the contents of the form, including various hidden fields and such, to ADF formatted XML. The XML is received by an email account which is supposed to parse the data. It was working. Now, six months later, for no reason I can figure out, it is not. The XML structure is exactly the same. The format of the email is still the same (text-only, non-HTML). Nothing has changed, but now it's not working.

The system is continuing to receive ADF / XML lead data from other sources without a glitch, but for some reason is no longer working with our stuff. Here is an example of what is sent:

```
<?XML VERSION=“1.0”?>
<?ADF VERSION="1.0"?>
<adf>
    <prospect>
        <requestdate>2012-11-30</requestdate>
        <vehicle>
            <year>2013</year>
            <make>Audi</make>
            <model>A4 2.0T</model>
        </vehicle>
        <customer>
            <contact>
                <name part="full">TESTING ADF LEAD FORM – XML STRUCTURE REVISED</name>
                <phone>(123)456-7890</phone> 
                <email>someonewho@isntme.com</email>
            </contact>
                <comments>Not Specified</comments>
        </customer>
        <vendor>
            <contact>
                <name part="full">VENDOR NAME</name> 
                <phone>123-456-7890</email>
                <email>test@autowebsite.com</phone>                                                                                                                       
            </contact> 
        </vendor> 
        <provider> 
            <name part="full">PROVIDER NAME</name> 
            <service>SERVICE</service>
            <url>http://somewhere.com/</url>
            <email>test@somewhere.com</email>
            <phone>123-456-7890</phone> 
        </provider>  
    </prospect> 
</adf>
```

Using native Wordpress mail function (might as well be using PHPmailer, same concept), and formatting as text. Basically sending a plain-text email with the above XML code as the body.

NOTE: Nothing has changed in the CRM that receives the data. No upgrades or modifications. It just simply stopped working, and can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with a similar issue for a few days now, and finally got it working with a couple of adjustments.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<prospect>
    <id source="Your_Company" sequence="1"></id>
    <requestdate>2012-11-30</requestdate>
    <vehicle status="" interest="buy">
        <year>2013</year>
        <make>Audi</make>
        <model>A4 2.0T</model>
    </vehicle>
    <customer>
        <contact>
            <name part="first">TEST_FIRSTNAME</name>
            <name part="last">TEST_LASTNAME</name>
            <email preferredcontact="1">someonewho@isntme.com</email>
            <phone type="voice">(123)456-7890</phone>
            <address>
                <street line="1">123 Main St</street>
                <city>SomeCity</city>
                <regioncode>MT</regioncode>
                <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
                <country>USA</country>
            </address>
        </contact>
        <timeframe>24 hours</timeframe>
        <comments>We put a disclaimer here.</comments>
    </customer>
    <vendor>
        <id source="Your_Company" sequence="1"></id>
        <vendorname>VendorName</vendorname>
        <contact>
            <name part="full">John Doe</name>
            <email>dealercontact@dealer.com</email>
            <phone type="voice">123-456-7890</phone>
            <address>
                <street line="1">123 Dealer St.</street>
                <city>DealerCity</city>
                <regioncode>MT</regioncode>
                <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
                <country>USA</country>
            </address>
        </contact>
    </vendor>
    <provider>
        <id source="Your_Company" sequence="1">Your_Company</id>
        <name part="full">Your_Company.com</name>
        <service>Your_Company.com</service>
    </provider>
</prospect>
```

It's not really inline with the ADF documentation, but its working well for us across several different CRMs.  I know the topic is a bit old, but I hope it helps!